# Visual studio does not see iostream, iomanip

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, iostream, iomanip

I downloaded '**visual studio code**' on a **Macbook air (M2)** and after running the program in C ++, visual studio gives an error 'iostream' file not found, 'iomanip' file not found. I think he does not see the standard libraries (it is not exactly known). Can you help please ? (By the way, in **Xcode** everything works fine).
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xgAr.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpCDO.png

Comment: Tag C++ for C++ questions. Do not tag C for C++ questions. Although this question is really neither; you have not fully installed a C++ implementation. Your actual question is how to install and configure everything you need to compile, link, and execute C++ programs with Visual Studio on macOS (a question I cannot help you with).

Comment: Please post the code as text not an images.

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;    
}

@toyotaSupra

Comment: Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code are not the same! Be clear with your naming, please. It would help if you include information about what version of XCode / XCode Deverloper Tools you have installed and whether you have any other C++ build toolchains installed.